# DSA : Finding Largest Rectangle avoiding Stones

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, histogram, dynamic-programming

Given a N * M Grid of characters, as shown below:

00010 
00110 
00000

where '1' indicates a stone, find the rectangle with the largest perimeter such that the edges of the rectangle don't hit any stones. In the above example, the answer would be:

**00**010 
**00**110 
**00**000

Another example would be:

Q)
011000
000000
000110
000110
000000

Ans
011000
**000000**
**0**0011**0**
**0**0011**0**
**000000**

What is the fastest way of solving this problem? Is it even possible to solve this in O(N*M) time?

**Note : The question was edited to find the rectangle with the largest perimeter.**

Comment: Do you mean O(MN) time? O(N^2) time is never possible because M could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: And are you sure you want largest area, and not something else like perimeter?

Comment: @orlp I got this question for a coding interview and it was not exactly clear about what to find. It said 'find the perimeter of the largest rectangle'.

Comment: That is exactly what I suspected. The largest perimeter seems a lot easier than the largest area.

Comment: @orlp If u know the solution could u answer it? Or give hints?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I do know that perimeter likely should be easier, as it has easier substructure.

Comment: @orlp chill.....no worries

Comment: [https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110761/how-to-find-maximum-perimeter-of-rectangle-in-a-grid-with-obstacles-dynamic-pr](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/110761/how-to-find-maximum-perimeter-of-rectangle-in-a-grid-with-obstacles-dynamic-pr)